# Are tickmarks for swipe views navigation available to use in Android?

Tags: android, swipeview

I want to create a set of pages in an Android app that swipe horizontally and use tickmarks to indicate the position of the current page within the set of 12 pages that I have.

The design pattern of using tickmarks like this is mentioned in the Android design documentation. 
http://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html
See figure 7

Are tick marks implemented as part of class within Android or do I need to create my own? Has anyone implemented tick marks who would be happy to share their code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This library by JakeWharton looks like it will do the job. 
http://viewpagerindicator.com

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a third party or you are rushing, you may want to use a RadioGroup as the tickmark or page indicator  with each of the RadioButton corresponds to each page, You may put a text label on each page and the radio button group must be in horizontal orientation just like the tickmark.

It will also add some intuitive function because when the user tick a radio button it will go directly to the intended page without needing to traverse all of the pages.