# Scrolling tabs like this?

Tags: android, user-interface

The Android developer site shows an example in [Providing Descendant and Lateral Navigation](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/descendant-lateral.html) Figure 7 (Labels/third one down in the image) which I'd like to use in my app. I can't find any reference to how to make this effect. The closest I found was a post in reference to the second item (tick marks) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20094570/are-tickmarks-for-swipe-views-navigation-available-to-use-in-android). Is this supported in Android or is there a library I could use?

[image]

Comment: I think you need [this](http://naeemgik.blogspot.com/2013/09/android-custom-scrollable-tabs.html)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should look into ViewPager with FragmentPagerAdapter. [Here is an example showing how to do so.](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter)

[Here is another example from the android developer site](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html)

[Finally from Jake Wharton an example with different icons and views for tabs to help you understand how to customize the view.](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator)

In case these links die in the future here is the main part from the developer site:

---

You can create swipe views in your app using the ViewPager widget, available in the Support Library. The ViewPager is a layout widget in which each child view is a separate page (a separate tab) in the layout.

To set up your layout with ViewPager, add a  element to your XML layout. For example, if each page in the swipe view should consume the entire layout, then your layout looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

To insert child views that represent each page, you need to hook this layout to a PagerAdapter. There are two kinds of adapter you can use:

### FragmentPagerAdapter

This is best when navigating between sibling screens representing a fixed, small number of pages.

### FragmentStatePagerAdapter

This is best for paging across a collection of objects for which the number of pages is undetermined. It destroys fragments as the user navigates to other pages, minimizing memory usage.